# grouping rows that go from negative to greater than or equal to 0

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm attempting to group together instances where an account balance in a single account goes from negative to greater than or equal to 0. For instance, in the table below account1 goes from negative to greater than or equal to 0 three times. I'd like to automate a way to group these together and differentiate them. Below is a sample table of what I'm working with

[image: sample table]

At this point, I am manually going in and making each instance unique. Below is the desired outcome

[image: desired results table]

Here's my code that manually creates the above table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT acct_nbr,
CASE
    WHEN acct_nbr = 'account1' AND row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN acct_nbr || 'a' --first instance
    WHEN acct_nbr = 'account1' AND row_num BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN acct_nbr || 'b' --second instance
    WHEN acct_nbr = 'account1' AND row_num BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN acct_nbr || 'c' --third instance
    ELSE acct_nbr
END AS acct_upt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `0` is not positive.  But, in any case, each group seems identified by the number of non-negative values *after* it.  However, that produces descending number and you want an ascending number.  Easily fixed using `dense_rank()`.

Finally, getting letters to append doesn't make sense.  So, I'll just add the last part as a separate column and you can figure out how to combine the information with the account number:

```
select acct_nbr,
       dense_rank() over (partition by acct_nbr order by grp desc) as modifier, 
       row_num, sys_dt, end_bal
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when end_bal >= 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by acct_nbr order by sys_dt) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately Teradata will not cooperate when I try to use to this

Comment: What do yo mean "Teradata will not cooperate"?  Teradata definitely supports window functions.